# PHP not automatically casting?

Tags: php

I am calling a function which requires a integer parameter. I am getting this integer from a http request so it is a string initially (ie. `"2" not 2`). My understanding based on the [integer casting documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) was that a string solely containing an integer like this would automatically be cast to an int  when required if possible. In this particular case, I am getting a `given non integer` error. I've already confirmed that doing an explicit `(int)` cast does work as expected.

How does the auto-casting in php work? Why, in general, might a situation like this arise where it doesn't automatically cast something that would become valid?

Comment: "In this particular case": which particular case is it?

Comment: does your file starts with `declare(strict_types = 1);`?

Comment: As @docl has mentioned, you're most likely [using strict types](https://3v4l.org/84iMH). Without it it should [work fine](https://3v4l.org/8PKV7).

Comment: Type Declarations for function arguments do NOT cast, they throw an error if argument is not of declared type https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: @AbraCadaver Primitive types do get casted/"juggled" in non-strict mode, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no auto-casting in function calling when you use strict types. When you have:

```
public function test(int $var) {
 //....
}
```

You can't pass any type, but integer.

```
$variable = "2";
test($variable) // not allowed
test((int) $variable) //allowed
```